# Is there a difference between NSString compare: and isEqual(ToString):?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Occasionally I find code which tests if two `NSString`s are the same like this:

```
if ([str1 compare:str2] == NSOrderedSame) {
    // Do something
}
```

Now, I believe this is less readable than using `isEqualToString:` and it also has some nasty side effects, like if `str1 == nil` the if(..) evaluates to true, or when `str2 == nil` havoc might break upon us according to the Apple docs. (**Edit**: As hatfinch points out, if `str1 == nil && str2 == nil` both variants produce the wrong result. So you need to guard yourself against this case anyway).

But before I crusade against those statements in my companys code, I wanted to make sure I didn't miss some important point.

So my question basically boils down to: Is there any difference between a `compare:` to `NSOrderedSame` and `isEqual:`?

Comment: NB if both str1 and str2 are nil, [str1 isEqualToString:str2] doesn't return the right result either...

Comment: True, but with compare: either string being nil is a problem. So you can do e.g. [@"Foo" isEqual:somestring] without testing somestring for nil. This you cannot do with compare:.

Comment: The pitfalls are worse with `compare:`, but in a side-by-side comparison of `-compare:` and `isEqual:`, highlighting the former as being susceptible to a specific class of bug (nil receiver with BOOL result) while staying silent on the latter could be misconstrued.

Comment: Agreed, I updated the question to point this out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reading the docs, the only differences I can find that you haven't already mentioned are:

1. `isEqualToString:` first compares the `id` of the two strings, which is a potential speed gain in an application that makes frequent re-use of strings. From the NSString reference:

   > Return Value:
   >   YES if aString is equivalent to the receiver (if they have the same id or if they are NSOrderedSame in a literal comparison), otherwise NO.
2. `isEqualToString:` is really more analogous to `compare: options:NSLiteralSearch`, as can be seen in the above quote. NSLiteralSearch is more finicky about Unicode character representation:

   > “Literal” when applied to string comparison means that various Unicode decomposition rules are not applied and Unicode characters are individually compared. So, for instance, “Ö” represented as the composed character sequence “O” and umlaut would not compare equal to “Ö” represented as one Unicode character.

This is really just nitpicking compared with the false positives and undefined behavior mentioned in your question.

Source: [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_)

Comment: Ah, I didn't stumble upon what you mention about NSLiteralSearch. So I guess if unicode decomposition matters, it might make sense to use compare:.

Comment: This answer just saved me! I'm reading data from a file which seems to use both e+U0301 and U00e9 to get a French é. I was putting these strings in HTML and then comparing against the originals to process tapping on a link. Sometimes my comparison was failing to find a match. I now know this is because I was using `isEqualToString` and my programmatically-generated href HTML text must have converted the e+U0301 to a U00e9 as it was being created. This meant that what appear to be identical strings longer matched! Using `compare:` with no options solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Similarly, iTunes uses composed character sequences in its song metadata, so if you are trying to find a song title containing accent marks in the music library, `compare` would work but `isEqualToString` wouldn't.