# What is purpose of using NSOrderedSame?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between NSString compare: and isEqual(ToString):?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877418/is-there-a-difference-between-nsstring-compare-and-isequaltostring)

What is the purpose of using NSOrderedSame in the below line of code?

```
if([result caseInsensitiveCompare:@"ERROR"]==NSOrderedSame)
```

> where result is a string variable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The compare methods in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch return how the compared objects should be ordered, instead of just returning a boolean that tells whether the values are the same or not. There are three values:

- `NSOrderedAscending`: The left operand is smaller than the right operand.
- `NSOrderedSame`: The two operands are equal.
- `NSOrderedDescending`: The left operand is greater than the right operand.

So your code simply checks whether the string pointed to by `result` is equal to the string *"ERROR"*, ignoring differences in case (that is, *"error"*, *"eRRoR"* etc. are all considered to be equal to *"ERROR"*).